# How to set Solid label in bar chart using Chart JS

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

How to set label like amount format (10,000) in bar chart using chat js (Without tooltip)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do it is showing label without necessarily having 'mouseover'. This can be done with `options` `onAnimationComplete` and `tooltipevents`.

Just pass empty array to `tooltips`, like below:

```
var options = {
  tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",

  showTooltips: true,

  onAnimationComplete: function() {
    this.showTooltip(this.datasets[0].points, true);
  },
  tooltipEvents: []
}
```

I hope this at least gives you an idea to proceed.

Comment: Thanks , I found another way                                                                            function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
}